# How to select the first item in the autocomplete suggestion primefaces jsf automatically

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete component from primefaces and in a specific case when the user input a value that contain "-" I need automatically to select the first item that show in suggestion without the user need to click or press enter in item to get the value.

In the first time I try to resolve the problem in my ManagedBean but I couldnt, this way below:

Autocomplete:

```
                    <p:autoComplete value="#{emprestimoFrm.matricula}"
                        dropdown="false"
                        completeMethod="#{emprestimoFrm.navegarMatricula}" var="item"
                        itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.alunoNomeTurma}"
                        converter="#{emprestimoFrm.conversorMatricula}"
                        emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." queryDelay="800"
                        rendered="#{emprestimoFrm.habilitarAluno}"
                        onclick="this.value=''">
                        <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="frm:dados"/>
                    </p:autoComplete>
```

Complete Method:

```
    List<IMatricula> navegarMatricula(String prefix) {
    Matricula[] colMat = null
    try {
        matriculas.clear()
        prefix = prefix.trim()
            if(prefix.contains("-")) {
                tipoLanctoSelecionado = "2"
                colMat = matricula.pesquisar(nome, DataHora.anoCorrente)
                //Goes to copy the first ArrayList object to value AutoComplete    
                Bean.copiarPropriedades(matricula, colMat[0])
                matriculas << colMat[0]
                return matriculas
            }else {
                if(prefix.isNumber()) {
                    colMat = dominio.emprestimo.matricula
                }else{
                    colMat = matricula.pesquisar(prefix,DataHora.anoCorrente)
                }
            }
        for (Matricula item : colMat) {
            matriculas << item
        }
    }catch (ex) {
        imprimirErrosPagina(ex)
    }
    matriculas
}
```

Converter:

```
class ConversorNavegacaoMatricula implements Converter{

def matriculas = []

ConversorNavegacaoMatricula( def m) {   
    matriculas = m
}

@Override
Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent ui, String valor) {
    def dominio = null
    if (valor.isNumber()){
        String idMatricula = String.valueOf(valor)
        dominio = matriculas.find {it.idMatricula.equals(idMatricula)}
    }
    dominio
}

@Override
String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent ui, Object valor) {
    def rotulo = null
    if (valor) {
        rotulo = String.valueOf(((Matricula) valor).getIdMatricula())
    }
    rotulo
}}
```

but didn`t work, the component bring the list correct but dont update value with first item automatically.

So I try resolve in xhtml with jstl

```
                   <p:autoComplete value="#{emprestimoFrm.matricula}"
                        dropdown="false"
                        completeMethod="#{emprestimoFrm.navegarMatricula}" var="item"
                        itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.alunoNomeTurma}"
                        converter="#{emprestimoFrm.conversorMatricula}"
                        emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado." queryDelay="800"
                        rendered="#{emprestimoFrm.habilitarAluno}"
                        onclick="this.value=''">
                        <c:if test="${fn:contains(item, '-')}">
                            <c:set
                                test="$('#form\\:txtAutoComplete_panel .ui-autocomplete-item').trigger('click');" />
                        </c:if>
                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="frm:dados"/>
                    </p:autoComplete>
```

but the component dont accpet my command

Comment: I would not expect adding the jstl if/set to be of any use. I'd add a jquery based keyhandler to the component and then to a click

Comment: Can you do post a piece of code to show for me how I do this?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: I needed a example with the component autocomplete primefaces, it would be more enlightening

Comment: Client-side that is 'just' html, nothing `p:autocomplete` related. Try, get back with the results (including code) and we can comment on this.

Comment: Without clear example data or HTML / JS Code, we are unable to assist. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve